# Jenkins Build Monitor with stages

Tags: jenkins, jenkins-pipeline

is it possible to have a jenkins build monitor like [this](https://wiki.jenkins-ci.org/display/JENKINS/Build+Monitor+Plugin) one, that also displays the stages, like [here](https://wiki.jenkins-ci.org/display/JENKINS/Pipeline+Stage+View+Plugin)?

The stages view plugin is nice. But I want to show the stages of multiple job and display it on a build monitor.

Comment: In the latest version of Build Monitor plugin, the current stage name is displayed inside the job rectangle while the job runs. Is that what you're looking for?

Comment: Hey, thanks. That ist a good improvement. Having the Stage View of multiple Jobs below each other would be even better. I might use dashing for that.

Comment: I know it is a quite old topic, but I am exactly looking for the same thing: a view that list all the stages of the last build, and optionally, for multiple project (considering they are using the same stages)

Answer (score 2):

You might be able to use the "Job and Stage Monitoring" plugin, which can send stage info for every build to an influxdb/grafana installation - you could probably build a grafana dashboard that meets your needs.

https://plugins.jenkins.io/github-autostatus

Comment: Do you have an idea where I can find some examples how to build grafana dashboards based on data from this plugin?

Comment: Use this custom dashboard [Jenkins Build Status](https://grafana.com/grafana/dashboards/10557)